# Static value as hook input

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a fetching service that fetches new data asynchronously and I want to update a component when new data is fetched.

To simplify things, assume this is my setup:

```
class SomeService {
  static data;

  // can be called by other components (asynchronous)
  static fetchData = async () => {
    data = await someAsynchronousCall() // data gets a new value
  };
}

const HomeScreen = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('new data is: ' + SomeService.data);
  }, [SomeService.data]); // I want to trigger this once data changes

  return <View> ... </View>
};
```

I've tried something like this, but when `data` changes, the `useEffect` doesn't get called.

Is there a way to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: what are you trying to do here? why do you need to do this? sounds like the wrong approach. Data shouldn't live on the service as when you make a second api call the data from the first request would be gone no?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I fetch data asynchronously when my application starts and access it when I open the component that's responsible for displaying it. If the fetch isn't done yet, I want to display whatever it has in the `data` field and update once the call finishes (I have placeholder data in that data field). PS. I'm trying to keep my code as clean as possible, and I found this approach to be very clear.

Comment: Ok, so maybe it would make sense to write a hook that executes the fetch. This way your implementation on the `HomeScreen` would be something like `const [data, loading] = useMyFetch(SomeService.fetchData)`. You would need to change the service to not only cache the data like it is but also `return data`

Comment: @JohnRuddell The service is only there for that type of data. I have an article page, and the corresponding service is `ArticleService`, so when i first launch the app, I call `ArticleService.fetch()`, and by the time the user gets to the `ArticleScreen` (the view), the data is either loaded or almost loaded; if its almost loaded, I display  whatever is in there. If i later want to update the page, I can just call fetch again, and once new data comes, the content will change once again.

Comment: Sure, make the service return the preflight request when its already started, but each page should also attempt to load their necessary data. like if a user opens the app in the article page from a deep link for instance. You can have it be smart where it doesn't repeat the same requests but its a good way to make sure the data will load for a given page. That would also solve a lot of the weird issues you're having... If you want to post a codesandbox or something that gives more context I'd be happy to help you write it up :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell I appreciate the help! I think I'll heed the advice of the people below and start using Redux. It's probably a better practice for data management anyhow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

useEffect listen to state update. SomeService.data is a static variable. You should implement something like that using Hooks.

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  //Stand for componentDidMount (empty array dependancies)
  useEffect(()=>{
    setData(new SomeService());
  },[])
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('new data is: ' + data);
  }, [data]); // I want to trigger this once data changes

  return <View> ... </View>
};
```

Comment: So there's no way to separate the fetching logic into a different class? Because I do more than just make an asynchronous call. There's some logic in there that really doesn't concern the view.

Comment: Did you ever heard of Redux ? I think it might be the solution you are looking for. https://redux.js.org/

Comment: At first, it looks like a big scary monster but it gives you great architecture.

Comment: Or you can put all your logics insinde the fechting call.

Comment: Yeah, I should probably just start using Redux. Thanks!

Comment: I just think about it you can actually do const [data,setData] = useState(); and setData(new YourObject(...))

Comment: In the static class? I feel like I've tried that before, and it yelled at me.

Comment: You used the static class in the useState hook. Your hook is the class. So the re-render occurs you will need to use new yourClass() each time. So the reference updates and the re-render update the page.

Comment: I updated my answer, you have to call the fetch function in the class constructor. Each time you call new SomeeService() in the setData hooks the data will be updated.

Comment: Ah that's a good idea. I think I'll stick with redux tho for the future. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` run after every render by default (if there is no second parameter). And the second parameter of `useEffect` is for checking if it should re-run or not, **NOT trigger the `useEffect` to run**.

In your case, your `static data` may change, but there is nothing that makes your component re-render, so your `useEffect` function won't run.

You can make your data as *state* to make it re-render. Or somehow trigger re-render whenever your static data changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use context api to separate your fetching logic from your component.

```
import React from 'react'
const DataContext = React.createContext()

function DataProvider({children}) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await someAsynchronousCall()
      setData(data)
    };
    fetchData()
  }, [])
  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={data}>
        {children}
    </CountStateContext.Provider>
  )
}
export {DataProvider, DataContext}
```

In your component use useContext to get data

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const data = useContext(DataContext)
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('new data is: ' + SomeService.data);
  }, [data]); // I want to trigger this once data changes

  return <View> ... </View>
};
```

and wrap your app in DataProvider

```
const App = props => {
<DataProvider>
  <HomeScreen />
  {/* other component */}
</DataProvider>
}
```